# Shiny: get x, y axis locations from a plot from multiple clicks

Tags: r, shiny

The below code show how to get the x, y axis location from one click.

How can I get x, y axis locations from multiple clicks on the plot?

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1",
             click = "plot_click",
             hover = "plot_hover"
             ),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  })
  
  output$info <- renderText({
    xy_str <- function(e) {
      if(is.null(e)) return("NULL\n")
      paste0("x=", round(e$x, 1), " y=", round(e$y, 1), "\n")
    }
  
    paste0(
      "click: ", xy_str(input$plot_click),
      "hover: ", xy_str(input$plot_hover)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1",
             click = "plot_click",
             hover = "plot_hover"
  ),
  actionButton("reset", "reset", class = "btn-warning"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rv_click <- reactiveValues(tb = tibble(x = double(), y = double()))
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv_click$tb <- tibble(x = double(), y = double())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    rv_click$tb <- 
      isolate(rv_click$tb) %>% 
      add_row(
        x = input$plot_click$x,
        y = input$plot_click$y
      )
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  })
  
  output$info <- renderText({
    tb_click <- rv_click$tb
    if (nrow(tb_click) == 0L) return("Please click on the plot.")
    paste0(
      "click: ", sprintf("%02d", 1:nrow(tb_click)), " ",
      "x: ", round(tb_click$x, 1), " ",
      "y: ", round(tb_click$y, 1), "\n"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I added a reactive value `rv_click$tb` to record the click event. Also a reset button to, you know, reset.